# django 2.0 work with forms without jquery

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-urls

from django import forms

```
class Find(forms.Form):
    object_name = forms.CharField()

views.py
    def get_obj(request, object_name='000'):
        print(object_name)
        form = FindSSK()
        print(request.GET)

urlpatterns = [
    # path(r'ssk/<str:object_name>/', get_obj),
    re_path(r'^(?P<object_name>)#$', get_obj),
    path(r'', get_obj),

]


{% block find %}

<form class="form-inline ml-5" action="#" method="GET">
        {% comment %} {{form}}     {% endcomment %}
    {% comment %} <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter obj" aria-label="Search"> {% endcomment %}
    {% comment %} <input  type="text" > {% endcomment %}
    <input type="text" name="object_name" />
    <input class="btn btn-outline-success ml-1 fas fa-search" type="submit" >

    </input>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When i push to submit on forms, he will redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000/?object_name=001

But var object_name steal 000
result print in get_obj()

```
000
<QueryDict: {'object_name': ['001']}>
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Yes. Why would it be anything else? The data is in request.GET, not in a URL parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not able to get the argument needed because you're actually sending the value as a GET argument. However `object_name` is passed in your view as an argument and as URL parameter for your URL pattern, means that this should be included in the URL like `url/object_name/` == `http://127.0.0.1:8000/001/`. Not sure this is what fits better your need.

To send data to the view, you could use a POST request or a GET request as you did with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?object_name=001`.

For both options above, you don't need to have `object_name` as a parameter neither this `^(?P<object_name>)` in url pattern.

```
VIEW: def get_obj(request object_name='000'):
______________________
URL: re_path(r'^$', get_obj),
```

**method="GET"**: If you use GET request in form `<form class="form-inline ml-5" action="#" method="GET">` you could retrieve the value like the following

```
def get_obj(request):
    object_name = request.GET.get('object_name') # object_name is the field name in form
    print(object_name)
```

**method="POST"**: If you use POST request in form `<form class="form-inline ml-5" action="#" method="POST">` you could retrieve the value like the following

```
def get_obj(request):
    object_name = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        object_name = request.POST.get('object_name')
    print(object_name)
```

> If you use POST request, don't forget to add `{% csrf_token %}` in your form